# Test an int variable with a boolean in Java

Tags: java

I am still learning Java and am stuck and getting errors. Can someone help with a solution of how the best way to do this would be.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LeapYear2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int year;
    year = scan.nextInt();
    boolean boolVar1,boolVar2,boolVar3;
    boolVar1 = (year / 4);
    boolVar2 = (year / 100);
    boolVar3 = (year / 400);
    if (boolVar1 == true && boolVar2 == true && boolVar3 == true)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a leap year.");
    }
    else if (boolVar1 == true && boolVar2 == true && boolVar3 != true)
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a leap year.");
    }
    else if (boolVar1 == true)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a leap year.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a leap year.");
    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your problem is? Also, you don't need to use `boolVar1 == true`, just use `boolvar1`.

Comment: booleans can't do math. What conditions are you testing for?

Comment: `(year / 4)` is not a boolean. `(year / 4) == 0` is.

Comment: First explain your question? What u wanna ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an explicit comparison to make an expression `boolean`. You do not need an explicit comparison with `true` on `boolean`s, so the code should be as follows:

```
boolean boolVar1,boolVar2,boolVar3;
boolVar1 = (year % 4) == 0;
boolVar2 = (year % 100) == 0;
boolVar3 = (year % 400) == 0;
if (boolVar1 && boolVar2 && boolVar3)
{
    System.out.println("This is a leap year.");
}
else if (boolVar1 && boolVar2 && !boolVar3)
{
    System.out.println("This is not a leap year.");
}
else if (boolVar1)
{
    System.out.println("This is a leap year.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("This is not a leap year.");
}
```

Note that `boolVar != true` and `boolVar == false` is equivalent to `!boolVar`.

Comment: thanks for the help with this, first time using boolean and i didn't fully understand the Java tutorial I read

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know whether an `int` value is evenly divisible by another, you can do this:

```
boolVar1 = year % 4 == 0;
boolVar2 = year % 100 == 0;
boolVar3 = year % 400 == 0;
```

In Java, integer and boolean values are not interchangeable (unlike languages like C where 0 is false and any non-zero value is considered true). You need to use a comparison operator like `==`. The `%` operator is the remainder function, which (from the rest of your code) looks like what you want to be using.

P.S. In the future, when you are asking about how to deal with errors, it would be very helpful if you posted the error message(s) in your question.

P.P.S. You should get in the habit of giving your variables meaningful names. For example, I would replace `boolVar1` with `divisibleBy4`, etc. This will save you lots of headaches when you start writing more complex code.

Also, as others have pointed out, with a `boolean` variable `b`, recommended Java style is to use

```
if (...b...)
```

instead of

```
if (...b == true...)
```

and

```
if (...!b...)
```

instead of

```
if (...b == false...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need all those booleans. You can simply test:

```
if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)){
    System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
}
else if (year % 400 == 0){
    System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
}
else {
    System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year.");
}
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear code since there are, from the standpoint of code read / flow, nontrivial relationships between the boolean conditions.  Better to implement the rule directly.

Comment: @djechlin It would be if leap year calculation would change in the future..but for this scenario I think it's matter of perspective.

Comment: @Sajal Dutta 9 If you want to go this route then you can further simplify as follows:if ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))){
    System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
}      yet, I favor a more straightforward self documenting logic.

Comment: @Tarik Agreed. I didn't want to change for the sake of how OP coded. So, he can easily follow.

Answer (score 1):

use the modulo method for this.

```
if(year % 4 == 0){
    System.out.println("This is a leap year.");
}
```

and so on.  From what I can see you do not need to declare 3 separate int types for this.  Just reuse this in each conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

rather than calculating so many conditions just put the following code

`if(year%4==0)

       System.out.println("The given year is leap year");

else

       System.out.println("The given year is not leap year");`

There is no situation where you stuck up between int value and boolean.

Comment: Check how leap years are calculated and you will find out it's more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
boolVar1 = (year % 4) == 0;
boolVar2 = (year % 100) ==0;
boolVar3 = (year % 400) == 0;
```

Note that the original version would have worked in C.